# How to PHP call another page and get output as variable?

Tags: php

I would like to call a PHP page from a PHP page, and return the output of the page I called as a single variable.

`require` would not suit my purposes as I need the output stored as a variable for later use, rather than outputting it immediately.

IE:

```
page1.php
<?php

echo 'Hello World!<br>';
$output = call_page('page2.php');
echo 'Go for it!<br>';
echo $output;

?>

page2.php
<?php

echo "Is this real life?<br>";

?>
```

Would output:

```
Hello World!
Go for it!
Is this real life?
```

Comment: I would call it via http:// and cURL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: have page2.php output a var, then require\include could be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`require` is actually exactly what you want (in combination with output buffering):

```
ob_start();
require 'page2.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Does this allow passing parameters to the invoked script? I.e. require 'page2.php?foo=bar';

Comment: nope, it does not, but if you run it on the same server, it does share the global $_GET variable, so you can manipulate that to get what you want.

Comment: Hello. I did this but it returned a error: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0 . Do i have to change this setting in php.ini ? Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 24):

To clear up some confusion when using `file_get_contents()`, note that:

1. Using with the **full url** will yeild the **html output** of the page:

   ```
   $contents = file_get_contents('http://www.example-domain.com/example.php');
   ```
2. While using it with **file path** will get you the **source code** of the page:

   ```
   $contents = file_get_contents('./example.php');
   ```

Answer (score 8):

You could use the file_get_contents method, this returns a string containing the contents of the page you request - http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ob_start();
include('otherpage.php');
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

A better method would be to encapsulate whatever's being done in that other page as a function, which you can then call from both pages. This lets you reuse the code without having to mess around with output buffering and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, none of the solutions posted worked for me. Only the comment by [Ondřej Mirtes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476216/how-to-php-call-another-page-and-get-output-as-variable/26498018#comment9047525_7476216) worked. I wanted to execute a script, passing some parameters:

```
anotherscript.php?param=value
```

So, the solution was to use cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http".( ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")?'s':'' )."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."/anotherscript.php?param=value");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to create pdf from existing .php files.
From answers above i have 3 options:
1.rewrite .php files
2.use buffering:

```
$_GET["id"]="4";
ob_start();
include 'test.php';
$TextPDF = ob_get_clean();
```

3.get data by url:

```
$serv = "http".( ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on")?'s':'' )."://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$TextPDF = file_get_contents($serv.'/test.php?id=4');
```

I think i will use third option, then i don't have to modify existing files.

Comment: This answer seems to address a specific subtopic of the question.  If you believe one of the answers above yours is correct, mark it as such rather than rehashing it.