# PHP file to string

Tags: php, web

Basically I want to run a PHP file from another PHP file to get the output as a string. I also want to be able to pass variables into it.

For example:

```
$result = get_output('./otherfile.php', $vars);
```

I have no idea how to do it. any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476216/how-to-php-call-another-page-and-get-output-as-variable) and [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.stackoverflow.com/');
echo $contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two files, 'included.php' and 'launch.php':

**included.php**

```
<?php echo $hello;
```

**launch.php**

```
$hello = 'hi';
ob_start();
include('included.php');
$returned = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

In '$returned' you have stored the results of the 'included.php' code
(try to launch var_dump($returned));

As you can see, you can pass variables creating them before the inclusion of included.php. With ob_start you start to save the output of the page and then, with ob_get_contents, you put the result in a variable.