# Load JS outputted by PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want to load JS outputted from a PHP script. The PHP file is on external server.

If I try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wwwwww.de/adscript.php"></script>
```

`adscript.php` will output:

```
document.write("Hello World!");
```

I want to use that JS. How could I make it so that I can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="adscript.php"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to generate a html code that load a banner with that JS.

Comment: You want to replace your script tag with a visible HTML element that displays an ad? Use JS to insert the HTML

Comment: yes u are right when i load the external script the output is not coming?

Comment: sorry, I dont think you understand how javascript works... you should read more about it, it's fun!

Answer (score 1):

The `<script>` tag is only used for JS.

If the `adscript.php` is only JS, then you can download it from that server and save it as a `.js` in the same directory as your HTML file file and run it like normal JS.

---

**EDIT**

I think I understand your question a little better now. So, to clarify, you mean that you have a PHP file on another server, something like this:

*phpFile.php*

```
<?php
    echo 'document.write("Hello World!");';
?>
```

And it will produce a JS file. Then you want to use that output JS.

In the (PHP) file where you want to insert the JS, insert this code:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require 'OTHER_SERVER/phpFile.php';
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    echo "<script>$output</script>";
?>
```

This will [store the output (JS) into the variable `$output`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7476264/2397327). Then, you can write that to your HTML as a `<script>` element.

Comment: the output is javascript but there is a php code that looks into the db to output the specified code like document.write("Hello World!"); but i cant see "Hello World"

Comment: @EmHi Oh okay. I gotcha now. =) Let me update my answer.

Comment: the require in php dont open external files.

Comment: what i want to do is: i want that anything can add javascript code in own project, that will load bannercode from my server.